# How to stop saving cookies in expressjs cookie-session web app?

Tags: express, cookie-session

I want to dynamically set the option to save cookies or not using the cookie-session library. How to set the option to save session cookies or not?

Comment: define "dynamically"?

Comment: @hjpotter92 i meant if a condition met only to save session data